# Visual Studio 2008/2010: How to get custom user controls to show in the markup's intellisense immediately?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, user-controls, intellisense

What I do is 1) add new user control to project and 2) register it in the directive of the page I want to use it on.  When I go to use it, it's not yet available in intellisense.  It appears I have to close and reopen the project in order for it to be available to intellisense.  This has been my experience for many years with different installs of VS 2008/2010 on various machines and I am finally getting around to question why this is the case.

Comment: What language are you using?  Are the controls and usages in different projects?

Comment: VB.NET 4.0, but it happens with C#, as well, and with the 3.5 and 4.0 framework.  The usercontrol is in the current project (it's all one web app).

Comment: Try these two things 1. make sure there are no errors in the user control 2. build the project

Comment: There are no errors.  In fact, I rebuild the entire solution just to make sure, but I always end up having to restart VS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It takes a minute to propagate to the editor, but you can still declare the control in markup without any errors. Chances are by the time you're done declaring it, intellisense will have caught up.

I don't know if it's any faster, but you could try registering the user control(s) in the web.config. If you plan to use the control(s) in more than one place, the web.config would be more appropriate anyway.

Comment: These controls are only used on this one page, so I just use the page directive.  Under other circumstances, though, you're right about using the web.config.

Comment: Sometimes waiting works, other times it doesn't, but it's the closest answer I've come across that doesn't involved restarting VS2010 100% of the time =\

Answer (score 0):

Normally, I add my controls to the web.config, then do a "Rebuild" of the solution / site. I've never had any trouble with intellisense / control access after doing that... though I could be lucky.